# 1st day programmer else statement for calculator program

Tags: c#

Okay so I started this program earlier today to practice what I have learned so far. I am almost done with it except that I cannot get this else statement in the middle to work for me. For the choices in Math Operations I want to make it if the user chooses one that I do not have that it tells him its not an option and closes down/restarts but for some reason the else statement is making it where it says its not an operation regardless if I choose an actual operation. Here is my code.

```
    using System;

class Program 
{
    //varibale for do-while loop
    private static string endAnswer;
    public static void Main() // <----- The Entry point
    {
        //Variables
        string Choice1;
        string mathChoice;
        int Num1;
        int Num2;
        int Answer;

        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to use Lane's Custom Calculator? ");
        Choice1 = Console.ReadLine();

        if (Choice1 == "Yes")
        {
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to Add, Subtract, Multiply, or Divide? (Case Sensitive)");
                mathChoice = Console.ReadLine();

                //User inputs the 2 numbers


                //Math Choices
                if (mathChoice == "Add")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("What 2 numbers would you like to use?");
                    Console.Write("Number 1 is: ");
                    Num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.Write("Number 2 is: ");
                    Num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Answer = Num1 + Num2;
                    Console.WriteLine("The answer is: " + Answer);
                }

                if (mathChoice == "Subtract")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("What 2 numbers would you like to use?");
                    Console.Write("Number 1 is: ");
                    Num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.Write("Number 2 is: ");
                    Num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Answer = Num1 - Num2;
                    Console.WriteLine("The answer is: " + Answer);
                }

                if (mathChoice == "Multiply")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("What 2 numbers would you like to use?");
                    Console.Write("Number 1 is: ");
                    Num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.Write("Number 2 is: ");
                    Num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Answer = Num1 * Num2;
                    Console.WriteLine("The answer is: " + Answer);
                }

                if (mathChoice == "Divide")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("What 2 numbers would you like to use?");
                    Console.Write("Number 1 is: ");
                    Num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.Write("Number 2 is: ");
                    Num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Answer = Num1 / Num2;
                    Console.WriteLine("The answer is: " + Answer);
                }
//This is the else statement that is giving me problems!!
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("This is not an option! Shutting Down..");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }


                //varibale for while loop to continue if selected Yes.
                Console.WriteLine("Another Equation? ");
                endAnswer = Console.ReadLine();



            } while (endAnswer == "Yes");


            //Goodbye Message
            Console.WriteLine("Thank you for using my program, goodbye ");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
            **//If someone selects no for wanting to use my program. 
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not and option...exiting Program...");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }**
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of multiple If statements, try Switch statement. It is better.

Comment: step through your code in the debugger...

Comment: Or change your 2nd, 3rd and 4th `if` statements to `else if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to multiple use of if blocks, instead use if - else if - else block for your program, then only it will work.
Your code structure for "if part" should be like

```
`if(mathChoice == "Add")
{
//code
}
else if(mathChoice == "Substract")
{
//code
}
else if(mathChoice == "Multiply")
{
//code
}
else if(mathChoice == "Divide")
{
//code
}
else{
//This is not an option! Shutting Down..
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code did not work, is that you had multiple if statements, but no `else`.
`If-else` is a whole block.`else` will only correspond to a single if statement. So what you could have done, is make a cascade of `if-else` that ends up with a single `else` - where you define your fallback.

In your case, I would strongly suggest using a `switch` statement.
It will simply make your code more clear.

It is pretty much the same as and if-else statement. You can read more about switch [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/switch).

**Code:**

```
switch (mathChoice.ToLower())
            {
                case "add":
                    Console.WriteLine("What 2 numbers would you like to use?");
                    Console.Write("Number 1 is: ");
                    Num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.Write("Number 2 is: ");
                    Num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Answer = Num1 + Num2;
                    Console.WriteLine("The answer is: " + Answer);
                    break;

                case "substract":
                    Console.WriteLine("What 2 numbers would you like to use?");
                    Console.Write("Number 1 is: ");
                    Num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.Write("Number 2 is: ");
                    Num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Answer = Num1 - Num2;
                    Console.WriteLine("The answer is: " + Answer);
                    break;

                case "multiply":
                    Console.WriteLine("What 2 numbers would you like to use?");
                    Console.Write("Number 1 is: ");
                    Num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.Write("Number 2 is: ");
                    Num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Answer = Num1 * Num2;
                    Console.WriteLine("The answer is: " + Answer);
                    break;

                case "divide":
                    Console.WriteLine("What 2 numbers would you like to use?");
                    Console.Write("Number 1 is: ");
                    Num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.Write("Number 2 is: ");
                    Num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Answer = Num1 / Num2;
                    Console.WriteLine("The answer is: " + Answer);
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("This is not an option! Shutting Down..");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;

            }
```

Now, two things I want to discuss:

1. I noticed that you have your input *case sensitive*. There is no need to do so. You can simply do `somestring.ToLower()` and it will convert it into lowercase. Then, you simply compare it with a lowercase string.
2. You will learn about `default` if you read about switch statements. I just want to point out, that `default` is a fallback value, which gets chosen if there was no match with any of the `case` elements.